# create dynamic jquery variable name based off current innerhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Say, I have a div element named something like:

```
<div class="mysterywatch"> {{mysterywatch.righthereiswatch}} </div>
```

I would simply like to have a dynamic variable based off of the dynamic inner `html` content inside element '`.mysterywatch`' , so if the below is the current output / contents of `.mysterywatch` div element... *eg.*

```
<h3 class="mysterywatch">Watch1</h3>
```

..the jQuery variable associated with `$('.mysterywatch')` would be / update to `$Watch1`

```
var = $Watch1
```

*(All HTML / text that would populate in `.mysterywatch` would be valid variable syntax. This will be added to frontend validation)*

Comment: what happens if the inner html is not a valid variable name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how/why you would want a dynamic variable based off of the inner text of a dynamic piece of content, but here you go:

```
var _varname = $('.giantmysterbeer').text();
window[_varname] = 123;
```

Comment: `val()` should be used only with  `input, select, textarea`, use `html()` or `text()` instead